# How to set up two levels of redirection in bash?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

In a bash script, I'd like to:

1. output every logs into a file (`loglowlevel.txt`),
2. but make **only few** of them visible in terminal (high-level),
3. I have, say, 20 high-level logs and 60 low-level logs. Thus I'd like to keep low-level logs "redirection-command" free, and have the redirection stuff to high-level logs only.

### Take 1

I wrote a basic script that redirects `stdout` and `sterr` to FD 3. `loglowlevel.txt` is correctly populated. But I am stuck in specifying the option for the high-level logs.

```
#!/bin/bash - 

# create fd 3
exec 3<> loglowlevel.txt
# redirect stdout and stderr to fd 3
exec 1>&3
exec 2>&3

# high-level logs' redirection below is wrong
echo "high-level comment" 3>&1

# low-level logs should remain redirection-free, as below
echo "low-level comment"
ls notafile

# close fd 3
3>&-
```

Here is what it does:

```
$ redirect.sh
$ cat loglowlevel.txt 
low-level comment
ls: cannot access notafile: No such file or directory
```

I expected `high-level comment` to be printed on terminal as well.

### Take 2

Second script, different strategy:

```
#!/bin/bash - 

function echolowlevel() {
    echo $1 &>loglowlevel.txt
}

function echohighlevel() {
    echo $1 |& tee loglowlevel.txt
}

echohighlevel "high-level comment 1"
echolowlevel "low-level comment 1"
echohighlevel "high-level comment 2"
ls notafile
```

Here is what it does:

```
$ redirect.sh 
high-level comment 1
high-level comment 2
ls: cannot access notafile: No such file or directory
$ cat loglowlevel.txt 
high-level comment 2
```

Two problems here:

1. error message from `ls` is printed in terminal, whereas I need it only in `loglowlevel.txt`.
2. `high-level comment 1` has been eaten in `loglowlevel.txt`.

### Question

I prefer the idea behind **Take 1**. But how can I make `high-level comment` be output to stdout while keeping the two `exec` commands?

Comment: Do you know about [`tee(1)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/tee/)?

Comment: Output redirection takes output from one file descriptor to another, i.e, it's a one-to-one mapping. You can't have output go to two separate sources with redirection alone.

Comment: @CarlNorum I didn't know about `-a` option in tee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

FIFO=/tmp/fifo.$$  # or use tmpfile, or some other mechanism to get unique name
trap 'rm -f $FIFO' 0
mkfifo $FIFO
tee -a loglowlevel.txt < $FIFO &

exec >> loglowlevel.txt
exec 3> $FIFO

echo high-level >&3  # Appears on original stdout and in loglowlevel.txt
echo low-level       # Appears only in loglowlevel.txt
```

Comment: If process substitution is available, you need just two lines (if I got it right): `exec 3>> >(tee -a loglowlevel); exec >> loglowlevel.txt`.

Comment: @William that works, thanks.

@chepner `exec 3>> >(tee -a loglowlevel.txt); exec >> loglowlevel.txt`
line 4: syntax error near unexpected token '>'
line 4: 'exec 3>> >(tee -a loglowlevel)'

Comment: m-ric: You appear not to have process substitution, then. Are you using the `/bin/sh` shebang in William's script? If so, change it to `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: @chepner you're right! `dash` complains. With `#!/bin/bash`, your solution works. You should post it as an answer! Can you describe how `exec 3>> >` works, I have not seen this syntax in the [literature](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).

Comment: @m-ric A description of process substitution is available in the bash manpage.  It is a highly non-portable construct.  If used, it will effectively tie your script to bash and make it difficult to use any other shell.

Comment: Any other shell than `bash`, `ksh`, or `zsh`, and possibly some others. I agree it's not 100% portable, but it's not specific to `bash` alone.

Answer (score 1):

A shorter version of William Pursell's answer, for shells and operating systems that support process substitution:

```
exec 3>> >(tee -a loglowlevel.txt)
exec >> loglowlevel.txt

echo high-level >&3  # Appears on original stdout and in loglowlevel.txt
echo low-level       # Appears only in loglowlevel.txt
```

In this example, writing to file descriptor 3 effectively writes to the standard input of a background `tee` process that appends to the file "loglowlevel.txt".

Support for this feature varies. It's not part of the POSIX standard, but it is provided by at least `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh`. Each shell will require some amount of operating system support. The `bash` version, for example, requires the availability of named pipes (the object created by `mkfifo` in William's solution) or access to open files via `/dev/fd`.